# How to use WriteProcessMemory in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I cannot compile this code. Could I have a help? Thanks.

```
procedure ChangeOutsideDateTime(h: HWND; dt: TDateTime);
var
  st: TSystemTime;
  pst: Pointer;
  hDTP: Cardinal;
  hProc: THandle;
  dwWrote: DWORD;
begin
  DateTimeToSystemTime(dt, st);
  pst:= VirtualAllocEx(h, nil, SizeOf(st), MEM_COMMIT, 0);
  if pst <> nil then begin
    if GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, hDTP) > 0 then begin
      hProc:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, false, hDTP);
      if WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pst, @st, SizeOf(st), dwWrote) > 0 then begin
        SendMessage(h, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, hDTP);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
      end;
    end;
    VirtualFreeEx(h, pst, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
  end;
end;
```

It shows "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" at line where is using "WriteProcessMemory".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several mitakes in it.

- you are passing an `HWND` to `VirtualAllocEx()`, but it expects a `THandle` to an opened process instead.  And you are calling `VirtualAllocEx()` before you have opened the process handle.  And you are not requesting write acess to the allocated memory.
- when calling `OpenProcess()`, you are not asking for `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` permission, which `WriteProcessMemory()` requires.
- your use of `WriteProcessMemory()` does not match its declaration. That is why you are getting a compiler error.
- you are passing the `HWND`'s process ID as the `LPARAM` of `DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME`, but it expects the allocated `TSystemTime` pointer instead.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure ChangeOutsideDateTime(h: HWND; dt: TDateTime);
var
  st: TSystemTime;
  PID: DWORD;
  hProc: THandle;
  pst: Pointer;
  NumWrote: SIZE_T;
begin
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, PID);
  hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, false, PID);
  if hProc <> 0 then
  try
    pst := VirtualAllocEx(hProc, nil, SizeOf(st), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if pst <> nil then
    try
      DateTimeToSystemTime(dt, st);
      if WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pst, @st, SizeOf(st), NumWrote) then begin
        SendMessage(h, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, GDT_VALID, LPARAM(pst));
      end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pst, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProc);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

> Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

This is compiler error E2003. If you encounter a compiler error that you don't understand, the first thing to do is read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2033_Types_of_actual_and_formal_var_parameters_must_be_identical_(Delphi)). It says:

> For a variable parameter, the actual argument must be of the exact type of the formal parameter.

The function call which leads to this error is `WriteProcessMemory`. Let's look at its declaration:

```
function WriteProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; 
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```

There is only one `var` parameter here, the final parameter. The variable that you pass must be of type `SIZE_T`, but you passed a variable of type `DWORD`. That is the mismatch.

Some other comments:

- The call to `VirtualAllocEx` is bound to fail because you pass a window handle rather than a process handle.
- Semantically it makes no sense to test for positive thread ID. Test not equal to zero for success or otherwise.
- You don't check the `OpenProcess` return value. That could readily fail.
- You don't open the process with the `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` access right which is necessary for `WriteProcessMemory`.
- You leak the handle if the call to `WriteProcessMemory` fails.
- The return type of `WriteProcessMemory` is `BOOL`.
- `hDTP` is a strange name for a process ID. That name suggests you think it is the handle of the date time picker control. It's not. It's the process ID.
- You pass that process ID in the `SendMessage` call rather than the address of the system time that you just wrote.

Comment: Can you modify that procedure as your comment? Did you make a test? For BOOL, you can get TRUE/FALSE or 1/0. About SIZE_T, DWORD or integer are same.

Comment: You asked about a compiler error, which I covered comprehensively. What would I make a test of? I don't understand that?